# Typo3, Typoscript. Output timestamp of last published workspace

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I set up a TYPO3 6.2 with workspaces. All the content is changed in a staging workspace and published all together.
Now I want a label like "last changes: " on every page.

I don't want the date the page was changed, but the date the workspace edits were last published.

I got something like:

```
30 = CONTENT
30 {
    table = sys_log
    select {
        selectFields = tstamp
        where = (workspace = 1 AND tablename = 'tt_content' AND details_nr = 30 AND details = 'Published')
        orderBy = tstamp DESC
        max = 1
    }
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.stdWrap.field = tstamp
        10.stdWrap.wrap = (|)
    }
    wrap = <span class="tstamp">|</span>
}
```

I'm pretty much stuck here. There is no content rendered in frontend. I get the span, but the parentheses and their content is missing.

I tried to find examples, because the documentation is not that newbe-friendly written.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if your select statement is valid, but I think in the `renderObj` it should be `10.value.field` and `10.value.wrap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're looking for is stored in every workspace-aware table in the field `t3ver_tstamp` as unix timestamp. This field is updated only if data is published or "swapped", which is a special publish process.

Unfortunately the approach which selecting from the sys_log table won't work, since the relevant payload is PHP-serialized in the field log_data like e.g. `a:2:{i:0;s:4:"Test";i:1;s:7:"pages:1";}` (pointing to table `pages` with uid `1` in this example).

As far as I understood it, you want to retrieve the last point in time any record on a particular page has been published from a draft workspace to the live workspace - which means to select the maximum unix timestamp on any record for any table pointing to that particular page. Unfortunately this does not work with plain TypoScript, thus you have to implement a service implemented in PHP.

Given that you want to show the last publishing date for page with ID `123` that would require the following tasks:

- `SELECT t3ver_tstamp FROM pages WHERE uid=123...`
- `foreach (array_keys($GLOBALS['TCA']) as $tableName)`

  - `SELECT MAX(t3ver_tstamp) FROM $tableName WHERE pid=123 AND t3ver_wsid=0...`
- determine maximum timestamp in PHP from the above

Comment: The project I needed that feature is some long time ago, and I can't remember if and how it was accomplished.
But I'll mark this answer as correct, since it's an approach to the solution. --- And since TYPO3 6.2 LTS is out of date as of now, there may be other possibilities in the current LTS.

Comment: Hm, then what is the difference between `stamp` and `t3ver_tstamp`?

Comment: `t3ver_tstamp` is only updated when a version record gets published or discarded (see https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/0b58a8afe44605d56995f5e114ef550ad5a0e7e0/typo3/sysext/workspaces/Classes/Hook/DataHandlerHook.php). `tstamp` is modified every time a record gets modified...